# Verification of $\partial_{\boldsymbol a} \lVert \boldsymbol P(\boldsymbol a) - \boldsymbol b \rVert^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus

### The problem

I'd like to ask if I differentiated the following function $F(\boldsymbol a)$ correctly:

$$
F(\boldsymbol a) = \lVert \boldsymbol P(\boldsymbol a) - \boldsymbol b \rVert^2 \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \boldsymbol a} = \ ?
$$

where

$$\begin{align}
\boldsymbol a, \boldsymbol b &\in \mathbb R^{3}\\
\boldsymbol P&: \mathbb R^{3} \to \mathbb R^{3}\\
F&: \mathbb R^{3} \to \mathbb R
\end{align}
$$

and $\lVert \cdot\rVert^2$ is the squared norm (dot product).

### My attempt to solution

I proceeded by writing the dot product explicitly and differentiating w.r.t. each of the 3 components of $\boldsymbol a$:

$$\begin{align}
F(\boldsymbol a) &= (\boldsymbol P_1(\boldsymbol a) - b_1)^2 + 
(\boldsymbol P_2(\boldsymbol a) - b_2)^2 +
(\boldsymbol P_3(\boldsymbol a) - b_3)^2\\
%
%
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \boldsymbol a}
  &=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \partial_{\boldsymbol a1}\ F(\boldsymbol a)\\
  \partial_{\boldsymbol a2}\ F(\boldsymbol a)\\
  \partial_{\boldsymbol a3}\ F(\boldsymbol a)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

where $b_i$ is the $i$-th component of $\boldsymbol b$ (analogously for $\boldsymbol a$), and $\boldsymbol P_i(\boldsymbol a)$ is the $i$-th component of the vector $\boldsymbol P(\boldsymbol a)$.

The partial derivative of $F$ by $\boldsymbol a$'s component $i$:
$$\begin{align}
\partial_{\boldsymbol ai}\ F(\boldsymbol a) &= 2(\boldsymbol P_i(\boldsymbol a) - b_i)\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol P_i}{\partial \boldsymbol a}(\boldsymbol a)\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol a}{\partial a_i}(\boldsymbol a)\\
&= 2(\boldsymbol P_i(\boldsymbol a) - b_i)\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol P_i}{\partial a_i}(\boldsymbol a)
\end{align}$$

I could then rewrite $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \boldsymbol a}$ as:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \boldsymbol a} = 2\boldsymbol M(\boldsymbol P(\boldsymbol a) - \boldsymbol b)
\end{align}$$

where $\boldsymbol M$ is the diagonal-matrix created from $\nabla \boldsymbol P(\boldsymbol a)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For typing convenience let 
$$\eqalign{
 J &= \frac{\partial P}{\partial a} \,\,\implies \,\,
 J_{ij} &= \frac{\partial P_i}{\partial a_j} \cr
}$$

Find the differential of $F$ and then its gradient
$$\eqalign{
 F &= (P-b)\cdot(P-b) \cr\cr
dF &= 2(P-b)\cdot dP \cr
   &= 2(P-b)\cdot(J\cdot da) \cr
   &= \Big[2J^T\cdot(P-b)\Big]\cdot da \cr\cr
\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} &= 2J^T\cdot(P-b) \cr\cr
}$$
There's no reason to create a diagonal matrix $M$, use the full $J$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you! Is it a common approach to first find the differential and then work out the derivative?  

I'm sorry, I have no experience with matrix calculus. Do you know of any great book/study material on this topic (matrix calculus (maybe with einstein's summation notation))?